# Nested /F looping and If statements in batch file

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, nested

I have two .txt files. One contains numbers, and the other one contains filepaths. I want to combine these two files to a .csv. The combination is based on wether the number (from nrs.txt) is in the string of the filepath (nodups.txt).

Now I have the following code for this:

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

for /F %a IN (Output\nrs.txt) DO (
    SET "nrs=%a"

    for /F %b IN (Output\nodups.txt) DO (
        SET "pathstring=%b"
        SET csvdelim=,
        IF NOT x!pathstring:%nrs%=""!==x%pathstring% %nrs%,%pathstring%>>new2017.txt
    )
)

@endlocal
```

However, I keep having the following issues with the code:

1. The pathstring never seems to get set. (when I run the code without the if statement, The `nrs` variable gets set but `the pathstring is set to %b`). I've seen a lot of possible solutions on here already but none seem to work for me (setting variables like `!var!` and using `usebackq`).
2. The IF statement in the second for loop gets the following error message `=""!==x%pathstring% was unexpected at this time`. The `=""` should remove the nr. from the path (if its there). When I replace "" with something else it still does not work.

The file contents are:

File nrs.txt:

```
12345
12245
16532
```

nodubs.txt:

```
C:\tmp\PDF_16532_20170405.pdf
C:\tmp\PDF_1234AB_20170405.pdf
C:\tmp\PDF_12345_20170506.pdf
```

Desired output:

```
12345, C:\tmp\PDF_12345_20170506.pdf
16532, C:\tmp\PDF_16532_20170405.pdf
```

I really hope someone can help me out with this !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution use a different approach, based on [arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Load array from nodubs.txt file
pushd "Output"
for /F "tokens=1,2* delims=_" %%a in (nodubs.txt) do set "nodubs[%%b]=%%a_%%b_%%c"

rem Process nrs.txt file and show output
(for /F %%a in (nrs.txt) do (
   if defined nodubs[%%a] echo %%a, !nodubs[%%a]!
)) > new2017.txt
```

Comment: I prefer this solution since it is more clear to me, as to how it works (and if anything ever changes I know where to make adjustments). However, if I run it like this I don't get any output. If I remove the `@echo off` i get the following:

`C:\Path\Output>(if defined nodubs[12345] echo 12345, !nodubs[12345]! ) 

C:\Path\Output>(if defined nodubs[12245] echo 12245, !nodubs[12245]! ) 

C:\Path\Output>(if defined nodubs[16532] echo 16532, !nodubs[16532]! ) `

Comment: You may remove the parentheses that surround the for and the redirection, that is, change `(for ... )) > new2017.txt` by `for ... )` and then insert the `>>new2017.txt` redirection at end of `echo %%a, ...` line.

Comment: Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

- In a batch file for variables need two percent  signs.
- There is no need to put `%%A` into a variable, use it directly.

---

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
for /F %%a IN (Output\nrs.txt) DO (
    findstr /i "_%%a_" Output\nodups.txt >NUL 2>&1 || >>new2017.txt Echo %%a
)
@endlocal
```

- Instead of a second for, I'd use findstr to search for the entry of nrs.txt enclosed in underscores.
- if no find use condiotonal execution on failure `||` to write to the new file.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I was unclear. I need to append both the path and the number in the new file. Is that archievable with your way? Also for some reason the %%a gives me an '%%a was unexpected at this time' error. That is why I used %a (which did seem to work)

Comment: Please edit your question to include a sample of your desired output based on sample nrs.txt and nodubstxt

Comment: `%a` and `%b` as used in your examples doesn't work in a batch file and since you're post is tagged batch-file, @LotPings usage is correct.

Comment: @LotPings added a desired output. @Compo I ran tests with the windows CMD, I just learned that you can't use `%%A` there. My apologies

Answer (score 0):

According to changed preliminaries another answer.

```
@Echo on
Pushd Output
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=_" %%A IN (
  ' findstr /G:nrs.txt nodubs.txt'
) DO >>"..\new2017.txt" Echo %%B, %%A_%%B_%%C
Popd
```

sample output:

```
> type ..\new2017.txt
16532, C:\tmp\PDF_16532_20170405.pdf
12345, C:\tmp\PDF_12345_20170506.pdf
```